# themoviedb - Movie - Status Code 34

Tags: themoviedb-api

I am using themoviedb to query about a specific Movie. I have utilized Discover to get list of movies which works fine. Now based on Id for a specific movie I am attempting get details of the movie. My URL for getting details of movie gives me error - Status Code 34. I am not sure what is wrong in my URL.

http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie?id=150689&api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Can you please point out what I am doing wrong in above URL?

Answer (score 1):

That's not quite a valid request. The one you're looking for is:

```
http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/150689?api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Cheers.